# NHibernate exception while deleting object graph: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: nhibernate, cascade

I've got a scheme (fields aren't necessary):

[a busy cat http://picsearch.ru/share/image-BCE8_4E168F3B.jpg](http://picsearch.ru/share/image-BCE8_4E168F3B.jpg)

I've got mappings:

**Entity**

```
<class name="LogicalModel.Entity" table="`Entity`" lazy="true">
  <id name="Id" ..> ... </id>
  <bag name="Attributes" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="select" batch-size="1" access="property" inverse="true">
    <key column="`Entity`" />
    <one-to-many class="LogicalModel.Attribute" />
  </bag>
  <bag name="Keys" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="select" batch-size="1" access="property" inverse="true">
    <key column="`Entity`" />
    <one-to-many class="LogicalModel.Key" />
  </bag>
</class>
```

**Attribute**

```
<class name="LogicalModel.Attribute" table="`Attribute`" lazy="true">
  <id name="Id" ..> ... </id>
  <many-to-one name="Type" class="LogicalModel.Entity" column="`Type`" cascade="save-update" fetch="select" not-null="true" foreign-key="fk_TypeAttribute" />
  <many-to-one name="Entity" class="LogicalModel.Entity" column="`Entity`" cascade="none" fetch="select" not-null="true" foreign-key="fk_EntityAttributes" />
</class>
```

**Key**

```
<class name="LogicalModel.Key" table="`Key`" lazy="true">
  <id name="Id" ..> ... </id>
  <bag name="KeyAttributes" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="select" access="property" inverse="true">
    <key column="`Key`" />
    <one-to-many class="LogicalModel.KeyAttribute" />
  </bag>
  <many-to-one name="Entity" class="LogicalModel.Entity" column="`Entity`" cascade="none" fetch="select" not-null="true" foreign-key="fk_EntityKeys" />
</class>
```

**KeyAttribute:**

```
<class name="LogicalModel.KeyAttribute" table="`KeyAttribute`" lazy="false">
   <id name="Id" ..> ... </id>
   <many-to-one name="Attribute" class="LogicalModel.Attribute" column="`Attribute`" cascade="save-update" fetch="select" not-null="true" foreign-key="fk_AttributeKeyAttribute" />
   <many-to-one name="Key" class="LogicalModel.Key" column="`Key`" cascade="none" fetch="select" not-null="true" foreign-key="fk_KeyKeyAttributes" />
</class>
```

Now please take a look...
As you see, We've got **one-way** master association **KeyAttribute - Attribute**, so it's just many-to-one and I don't need back association at all.

Now the problem is when I'm trying to delete *whole graph* - delete Entity object (notice: Entity actually aren't loaded at all, it's just set of proxies, that's why NHibernate make additional SELECT queries to check references before delete)
like this

```
Session.Delete(Entity);  //  here PropertyValueException: 
//  not-null property references a null or transient value:  LogicalModel.KeyAttribute.Attribute

Session.Flush();  // Actually I use transactions in my code, but don't mind
```

SQL Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT entities0_.[Id] as Id1_1_, entities0_.[Id] as Id1_45_0_, 
FROM [Entity] entities0_ WHERE entities0_.[LogicalModel]=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='DC8F8460-9C41-438A-8334-97D0A94E2528'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT attributes0_.[Entity] as Entity12_1_, attributes0_.[Id] as Id1_1_, attributes0_.[Id] as Id1_16_0_, attributes0_.[Type] as Type11_16_0_, attributes0_.[Entity] as Entity12_16_0_ 
FROM [Attribute] attributes0_ WHERE attributes0_.[Entity]=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='63E4D568-EAB2-4DF2-8FED-014C8CB2DE22'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT keys0_.[Entity] as Entity4_1_, keys0_.[Id] as Id1_1_, keys0_.[Id] as Id1_43_0_, keys0_.[Entity] as Entity4_43_0_ 
FROM [Key] keys0_ WHERE keys0_.[Entity]=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='63E4D568-EAB2-4DF2-8FED-014C8CB2DE22'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT keyattribu0_.[Key] as Key4_1_, keyattribu0_.[Id] as Id1_1_, keyattribu0_.[Id] as Id1_0_0_, keyattribu0_.[Attribute] as Attribute3_0_0_, keyattribu0_.[Key] as Key4_0_0_ 
FROM [KeyAttribute] keyattribu0_ WHERE keyattribu0_.[Key]=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='103D8FB3-0B17-4F51-8AEF-9623616AE282'
```

So what we can see:

not-null property references a null or transient value: LogicalModel.KeyAttribute.Attribute
happened just after NH check field **Attribute** (not-null constraint in db, it's ok) in class **KeyAttribute** (see profiler log).

It's pretty fun, cause NH have to delete Attributes and KeyAttributes both, NH read information about Attribute field in KeyAttribute class, **FOUND** it in DB, **NOT FOUND** it in **NH session** (!!!) (cause Attributes was loaded before), and just throw this stupid error.

What I've already tried to do:
1. make not-null="false". In this case NH makes additional update - try to set Attribute=NULL - cause constraint violation in DB.
2. set lazy="false", lazy="no-proxy" on many-to-one association for KeyAttribute-Attribute - nothing;

Now I don't like the idea of interceptors because there are to many scenarios where I've got the same situation, I need common solution

Please, guys, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it may be caused by your lazy load on all entities of model.
When deleting entity, it loads and delete referenced Attribute list, loads referenced Key list, loads referenced KeyAttribute list (to have key of deletion) and then it falls in not-null property references a null or transient value because referenced Attribute has been deleted before in session.

You can check that by removing all lazy load in your mapping files.

A quick solution may be to keep lazy load but to force a full load of model (with hibernate initialize()) when deleting, for example in a Delete(Entity) static method in Entity factory.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I've tried to load full graph & kill lazy on Attribute off to make it non-transient (I just read all collections and links by iterating them :) ), it didn't help me ((

"..referenced Attribute has been deleted before in session.."
That may be!

Comment: @Vince: I don't think that it has anything to do with lazy loading.

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger, @Vince
I went to reflector, it seems NH requires external delete order control, cause in Attribute persistContext there is no information about Association to the KeyAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting on-delete="cascade" in

```
<class name="LogicalModel.Key" table="`Key`" lazy="true">
<id name="Id" ..> ... </id>
<bag name="KeyAttributes" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="select" access="property" inverse="true">
  <key column="`Key`" on-delete="cascade" />
  <one-to-many class="LogicalModel.KeyAttribute" />
</bag>
<many-to-one name="Entity" class="LogicalModel.Entity" column="`Entity`" cascade="none" fetch="select" not-null="true" foreign-key="fk_EntityKeys" />
```

Because in profile you will see nh trying to update something to null which is non nullable

Comment: Mmm.. I've tried right now, it doesn't help, cause NH still doesn't know that Attribute must be deleted with KeyAttribute together, but KeyAttributes first, without check Nullability.
In the end NH was trying to update link to Attribute, which is not null.

If we will see through reflector, the problem is in method DeleteEntity -> call method NHibernate.Engine.Nullability.CheckNullability:

public void CheckNullability(object[] values, IEntityPersister persister, bool isUpdate)

May be need to check that one

Answer (score 0):

NH sometimes requires to set references to null. Usually this is to avoid problems in models where circular references exist. But it is not always clever enough to find a way to avoid it, even if the is one.

So it may require to allow nulls in some foreign key fields, of course not only in the mapping file, also in the database. It actually *should* solve the problem.

---

**Alternatively**, you could also delete the data table by table using HQL. This works fine in  all cases where you don't have inheritance and if you know all entities and the order to delete them:

```
object entityId;

// gets keys to delete
List<object> keyIds = Session
  .CreateQuery("select id from Key where Entity = :entity")
  .SetEntity("entity", Entity)
  .List<object>();

// delete KeyAttribute which reference the key
Session.CreateQuery("delete KeyAttribute where Key.id in (:keyIds)")
  .SetParameterList("keyIds", keyIds)
  .ExecuteUpdate();

// delete the keys
Session.CreateQuery("delete Key where id in (:keyIds)")   
  .SetParameterList("keyIds", keyIds)
  .ExecuteUpdate();

// get attributes to delete
List<object> attributeIds = Session
  .CreateQuery("select id from Attribute where Entity = :entity")
  .SetEntity("entity", Entity)
  .List<object>();

// delete KeyAttributes which reference the attributes
Session.CreateQuery("delete KeyAttribute where Attribute.id in (:attributeIds)")
  .SetParameterList("attributeIds", attributeIds )
  .ExecuteUpdate();

// delete the attributes
Session.CreateQuery("delete Attribute where id in (:attributeIds)")   
  .SetParameterList("attributeIds", attributeIds )
  .ExecuteUpdate();

Session.CreateQuery("delete Entity where id = :entityId")   
  .SetParameter("entityId", Entity.Id)
  .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Note:

- You may break the parameter lists into piece if they exceed the size of around 2000 (in SQL Server).
- The session gets out of synch when deleting directly in the database. This doesn't cause any problems when deleting is all you do. When you are doing other staff in the same session, clear the session after deleting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I think that's pretty hard coding, especially in HQL! Now I'm trying to override CascadeBeforeDelete in own DeleteEventListener, I think I can set the right deletion order by that way

Comment: @EvgeniyK: wait a minute, I said that allowing nulls *should* solve the problem. The "hard coded" part is just giving you more control and may be a good performance optimization.

Comment: Yeap, If I drop all constrains in NH & MS SQL, of course everything would be alright, no question; In Russia it called: "unsportsmanlike behavior" =))

Comment: @EvgeniyK: I see it as a trade-off of using an ORM. You don't need to write everything in plain SQL, but you also can't influence the exact statements and order of SQL queries. So there *may* be some space for optimization (say: theoretically these constraints may work) but it is not supported by NH. I wouldn't worry about this too much.

Comment: @EvgeniyK: and as you can see: it is the only working solution, except of switching back to native SQL.